# Why does play/pause on my Bluetooth headset not work with Spotify on Windows 8.1?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-8.1, headset, spotify

In Windows 8 (8.1 specifically) the play/pause button on my Sennheiser Bluetooth A2DP headphones does not play or pause Spotify. The track skip buttons work, but not the play/pause button.

Windows 8 supports AVRCP as shown by the working skip buttons, and indeed all buttons work with Windows Media Player; just not the play/pause button with Spotify.

I'm at a loss of where to look to even diagnose this, as Spotify isn't like Winamp - its a bit of a black-box with its configuration and logging.

Perhaps this is just a Spotify bug; I will see if I can find some direct-line to support in parallel.

Spotify version: `0.9.6.81.gd359a796`

Comment: If it works in other players as expected, then it's a Spotify problem/bug.

Comment: https://support.spotify.com/, https://www.spotify.com/int/about-us/contact/

Comment: Did this ever start working for you?

Comment: Nope. I moved to using Outcoldplayer on Windows against Google Play Music. Logging a bug got me generic support responses.